# Does a label on source branch get applied to target branch upon merging

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge

My bugfixes branch has got a label (build001) applied. If I merge bugfixes branch till build001 back to live branch after deploying fixes to live, will it apply label (build001) to live branch?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Labels are a defined set of files/versions.  TFS won't change the label unless you manually choose to do that.